# Tkinter - Making the columns auto adjust to longest field value

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a simple inventory management system. I want the columns to be auto-adjusted to the `longest field value` in the column.[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vukkg.jpg) is the current solution. I want it to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaTY1.jpg).

This is how I initialize the treeview:

```
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview (height = 15, columns = ('amount',
        'size','price','status','best','comment'))
        self.tree.grid (row = 9, column = 0, columnspan = 7)
        self.tree.heading ('#0', text = 'Varenavn', anchor = W)
        self.tree.heading ('amount', text = 'Antall', anchor = W)
        self.tree.heading ('size', text = 'Størrelse', anchor = W)
        self.tree.heading ('price', text = 'Pris', anchor = W)
        self.tree.heading ('status', text = 'Status', anchor = W)
        self.tree.heading ('best', text = 'Best før', anchor = W)
        self.tree.heading ('comment', text = 'Kommentar', anchor = W)
```

I've read that the default of a column is the behavior I want. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a testable example. Some basic GUI and your imports.